# Cross platform development, GUI and Database - c#

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, mono, cross-platform

Forgive me for asking a common question, but I couldn't quite get what I needed from what I found so far.

**First question - SQLite**. I am using this DB as in my C#.NET 3.5 windows service and it works great, I was looking for a portable solution, because I would like port my service to a linux daemon etc, using Mono, which seems to support it. However, I am not sure how to implement this. I had thought the dll was compatable, but it seems there is a seperate dll for Mono/.NET which I should have expected. Does this mean I need to seperately code/compile for each platform or is there something that would allow me use of SQLite with the same code on various platforms? I have encountered [this](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) a few times in my searches, csharp sqlite, a "reimplementation". To be honest, this is quite new to me, is it of use? The Mono SQlite page says that they Mono.Data.Sqlite code is based on System.Data.SQlite and goes on to say...

> "We have chosen this way as means to
>   provide a migration path for
>   developers using SQLite in their .NET
>   applications"

Are they referring to creating a new, seperate binary? Or could I run my code as is with some adaptation?

**Second question - GUI**. As far as I can tell the two main options for cross platform dev in .NET would be GTK# and Winforms. Again however, its the specifics of implementation that are a bit hazey. Can I create a win forms GUI in visual studio as I normally would then easily migrate this using mono? Or should I develop this in something like X-Develop or MonoDevelop?

Many thanks for your advice/patience :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help out a little bit here I used the full mysql dll file that was provided and I was able to compile my program on windows using visual studio, and then deploy it to Linux without changing anything(except the case of the mysql dll file, which is kind of annoying you'll see what I mean at some point).

Also from what I've heard winforms isn't totally supported by mono yet, but I may be wrong. I haven't done a gui cross platform yet, but I would test winforms first, just so you could develop it in visual studio, and if that doesn't work I think GTK should be fine.

You just need to make sure that the dll's are compiled for .net 3.5 or below and you should be fine(90% of the time).

Check this out here, http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA  and also the link that chris provided.

Comment: Good answer; and I completely agree that going GTK is probably the best bet.

Comment: Cheers man! Could you tell me, was it just a matter of changing the contents of the project folder (and the reference)? I have not built such a large project before so im a little shady on how everything is put together. There is another componant to SQLite, another dll that I must add to my release folder, but cannot be referenced... will this be compiled with my program automatically?

Comment: Just compile it, move it to the linux computer and type "mono program.exe". If you get an error that says "Cannot find Whatever.dll" just make sure the case of the dll matches by using the command "mv whatever.dll Whatever.dll". That should help ya out.

Comment: @kelton52 - Hey kelton, this may be a strange question, but its relevant to this one Ive already asked, so maybe you could help. I was wondering if Mono can use System.Data.SQLite out of the box, as it seems it can. At the moment I am testing my service in MonoDevelop under both .NET and Mono, and both seem to work with the same DLL. Im in suspicious "its too good to be true" mode :P If it makes any difference, I am using the latest long term supported (and therefore slightly older) version of Mono, 2.6.7. Will I get a nasty surprise when I move the exe over to linux?

Comment: Most dll's don't need to be recompiled or anything. I used the full mysql dll file that wasn't designed for mono and it seemed to work fine.